# vim automatically formatting html files with tidy and <script> tag with Jsbeautifull

Tags: javascript, html, vim, formatting, script-tag

How can I format html files in vim using [tidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/) and format just the contents of the script tags using [Jsbeautifull](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2727)?

I have this command: `:%!tidy -i -xml --char-encoding utf8 --wrap 0 --show-errors 0 2>/dev/null` for formatting html files,

and this `:call g:Jsbeautify()` for formatting the js file. How can I call `g:Jsbeautifull()` just on the contents of the script tags? `Jsbeautifull(js_script, options)` can take the js source as argument.

And I want to map it to `<C-S-f>`.

Comment: control-shift is probably not recognized by vim.

Comment: I have other formating tools on `<C-S-f>` for other file types, and it works.

Comment: @microo8 Have you checked whether `<C-S-f>` yields the same result as `<C-f>`? It must not work because 1. internal representation of input queue is unable to hold this sequence; 2. terminal emulators are likely to send this sequence as `<C-f>` (rxvt-unicode) or even not send it at all (konsole); 3. the fact that my vim after doing `nmap <C-S-f> smth` is launching `smth` when I run `<C-f>` means that `<C-S-f>` is translated to `\x06` (`^F`) when parsing `:map` arguments.

Comment: ok, it probably isnt recognized so i map it to `<C-f>`. But that is not the answer of my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So when nobody answers my question, I had to learn some vim scripting and I made it!

I have copied the `~/.vim/plugin/jsbeautify.vim` to `~/.vim/plugin/jsbeautify_replace.vim` and  modify it. Here is a `diff jsbeautify.vim jsbeautify_replace.vim`:

```
1c1
< if &cp || exists("loaded_jsbeautify")
---
> if &cp || exists("loaded_jsbeautify_replace")
4c4
< let loaded_jsbeautify = 3
---
> let loaded_jsbeautify_replace = 3
286,291c286
< "function! g:Jsbeautify(js_source_text)
< function! g:Jsbeautify()
<   if !s:is_js()
<       echo "Not a JS file."
<       return
<   endif
---
> function! Jsbeautify_replace(js_source_text, indent)
310c305
<   let lines = getline(1, "$")
---
>   "let lines = getline(1, "$")
312,313c307,308
<   let s:input = join(lines, "\n")
<   "let s:input = a:js_source_text
---
>   "let s:input = join(lines, "\n")
>   let s:input = a:js_source_text
617c612
<   
---
> 
619,622c614,615
<   :g/.*/d
<   let @0 = ret
<   :put!0
< endfunction
---
>   let lines = split(ret, '\n')
>   let result = ""
624c617,624
< nnoremap <silent> <leader>ff :call g:Jsbeautify()<cr>
---
>   for line in lines
>       let result .= a:indent."  ".line."\n"
>   endfor
>   ":g/.*/d
>   "let @0 = ret
>   ":put!0
>   return a:indent."<script type=\"text/javascript\">\n".result.a:indent."</script>"
> endfunction
```

And have written some script in `~/.vim/plugin/tidy_jsbeautify.vim`:

```
function! g:tidy_js()
    %!tidy -i -xml --char-encoding utf8 --wrap 0 --show-errors 0 2>/dev/null
    %s#\(\s*\)<script\_\s*type="text/[jJ]ava[sS]cript"\_\s*>\(\_.\{-1,}\)</script>#\= Jsbeautify_replace(submatch(2),submatch(1))#g
endfunction
```

This calls tidy on my buffer and then on all script tag contents the jsbeautify + the indent of the script tag will be added. And then in `~/.vim/ftplugin/html.vim`:

```
:map <buffer> <C-f> :call g:tidy_js()
```

And now is my whole html file nicely formated just with a shortcut `CTRL+F ENTER` :)

Answer (score 0):

In `jsbeautify.vim`, line 310 shows this is not possible if you don't modify the plugin:

```
let lines = getline(1, "$")
```

Probably you want to customize that part (modify the function `g:Jsbeautify()` to take two arguments and use `getline(a:start, a:end`) instead.

Comment: OK so when I just change the `g:Jsbeautify()` to `g:Jsbeautify(start,end)` and the line 310 to `let lines = getline(start, end)` it will be good?

Comment: @microo8: line 310 you have to use `a:start` and `a:end` if arguments are called `start` and `end`. Inside a function the `a:` prefix is used for argument variables.

Comment: OK so I changed the `let lines = getline(1, "$")` to `getline(a:start, a:end)`. Now what?

Comment: @microo8: now select whole lines of JavaScript, and `:call g:Jsbeautify(line("'<"),line("'>"))`. Make backups, I did not try that.

Comment: But how can I call tidy, then select the JS lines and then `:call g:Jsbeautify(line("'<"),line("'>"))` in one map command?